# PageSpeed Insights and php include

Tags: php, html, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

I'm cleaning up the web page (HTML and PHP) code to improve the PageSpeed Insights reports and I noticed a bad result using PHP *include* (or *include_once*).

To share common code between pages I use to copy the code to external files (ie inc_header.php ) and include them in more pages. It is a consolidated practice.

Today I noticed relevant different results in PageSpeed if I test a static page or the same page using a couple of included files.

Is it true that PHP includes influence the PageSpeed Insight score? What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: who told you that copying files' contents instead of including it will enhance the performance?

Comment: I did both tests and I got surprised to see the test differences.

Comment: @Uncoke Please check [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/63263/seo-impact-when-using-php-include#answer-85265). PHP script execution speed can become an issue if configured badly serverside. Thus, the possible difference in [TTFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_first_byte) for static HTML pages.

Comment: As PHP runs on the server, PageSpeed cannot detect such an include. What is that "bad result" you have seen? Is the performance lower? Does the result look different?

Comment: @hassan copying the output of the include to the page enhances performance as the PHP does not have to be executed.

Comment: @NicoHaase the PHP has to be executed, which takes time. Page Speed is all about detecting this. Yes, the performance of a page with a heavy include will be lower and the result will look different (larger TTFB).

Answer (score 0):

The include can do a lot of invisible requests (database requests for example) to generate the code. If you serve a page without server side includes, you will get a lower TTFB. In other words: the results you are seeing can be exlained and are as expected.

A common trick to tackle this delay is to use a Static Site Generator. SSG's generate static pages that contain the output of these includes (preventing the extra requests).

Another trick to tackle this is to use a cache layer. A cache layer does (almost) the same as a Static Site Generator. When you cache (the output of) your request you prevent these invisible requests too.

Comment: "The include can do a lot of invisible requests (database requests for example) to generate the code" - can you share more details about this? If the exact same code is used, but only outsourced into different files (instead of a single file), how should these "invisible requests" pop up?

Comment: I assumed the output/generated code was used/copied instead of the (same) code. They do not pop up, as they are server side requests.